# Lipo - ESC - Motor combinations

Tags: lipo, motor-controller

I wish to find out the right combination for my quadcopter.
I have 2300 KV motors (4), 12 Amp ESC (4) and 3S 2200 mah 20C Battery. I have read this combination is great for a 300 mm quadcopter. However, it seems my math is slightly off.

The battery will provide me 44 Amp current at any time. However the 4 ESC will demand 48 Amp. Should the battery be changed to higher rating.

I don't know how to determine 2300 KV motor requirement. Will the above ESC and battery be sufficient for the motor? I know weight of QC and size of propellers are also additional factors. Hope someone can explain how these must be matched.

Comment: Usually you want some margin, right now your margin is negative.

Comment: There are nice tables over the internet for drones hobbyists, designed to help with these decisions. The only thing you need to do is to search a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If the 20C is continuous, burst capacity (usually <10s) will likely be something like 30C so you should be fine. I am not sure what props etc you are running but 12A escs seem a bit low, as your motor / prop combination will determine the current draw, and the escs may burn on a sustained full throttle 'punch'. If your quad only draws what you believe it will draw, then your battery should be fine! (for reference I run 20A escs on a 225mm with 6inch standard two blade props / 2300kv 2205 motors, 621g flying weight (tilt rotor) - I use 1300mah, 4s, 40c (60c burst) with that combination, not optimal and I want bigger batteries). It will alsodepend how you intend to fly also, as racing will be more demanding than hovering, etc...

Comment: P.s. Often, if you google your motor or similar you can find some people that have performed thrust tests with different props and 3s, 4s lipos, etc. This should give you an indication of expected current draw and what rating of esc should survive, then you can do the math for battery discharge again :) - so work backwards from the motor with expected prop, then choose esc, then batteries!